# How to configure AWS or Google Cloud instance to resolve "DX11 feature level 10.0 is required" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, configuration, google-cloud-platform, streaming

I'm trying to set up a Cloud server for a streaming service based on this documentation: https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Platforms/PixelStreaming/Hosting

I tested with AWS (P2 instance with Nvidia Tesla K80) and Google Cloud (equipped with Nvidia Tesla P4 virtual workstation) on Windows Server 2016. The problem is when we tried to launch Unreal or a game, **I got this error: "DX11 feature level 10.0 is required to run the engine."**

I'm not sure to understand very well how GPU works on the Cloud. A lot of hosting service sell them as high-performance computing solutions (computational fluid dynamics, speech recognition, autonomous vehicles). But what I want is 3D rendering, application streaming, and video encoding. So maybe I didn't test with a good configuration.

**What kind of configuration can we resolve this error?**

Here what we tried:

- Install latest Nvidia drivers for the specific GPU
- Install latest DirectX
- Enable Media Foundation in Windows Server Manager

A similar question was asked by another user here: [Reddit AWS question](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/aqagdy/aws_g3_p3_p2_instances_running_ue4_getting_error/) and here [Unreal developer Network](https://udn.unrealengine.com/questions/487396/how-to-resolve-dx11-feature-level-100-is-required.html) without answers.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution to this problem!

- On AWS, I changed from a P2 instance to a G3 instance with a Windows
  Server 2016 base AMI.
- You should use a product based on the Remote
  Framebuffer Protocol (RFB), such as a member of the VNC family. In my
  case, I used TightVNC. If you use a product that is based on RDP,
  your code will not be able to detect the presence of the GPU.
- Before installing the correct driver, you will need to disable the Basic
  Display Adapter in Device Manager.
- To install the driver, you need tofollow theses instructions: [Installing NVIDIA GRID Drivers for G3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/install-nvidia-driver-windows.html).
- From there, you need to reboot your instance.
- Open UE4 and enjoy!

Comment: The link for the driver install instructions changed slightly: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/install-nvidia-driver.html . Otherwise the GRID drivers worked for me on an g4dn.2xlarge.